# Adobe Air - Alternative to encrypted local storage

Tags: android, air, storage

How to store sensitive data in an *Air Android* app? *Encrypted local storage* seems to be not supported in Adobe Air 2.5

Comment: You can also create you one encrypt layer use AES; RC4 or more. (If you only need a simple encryption RC4 is easy to use.) But you will has the key handle problems here.